# How to load balance Storm MQTT Spouts

Tags: mqtt, apache-storm

I'm new to Storm, but I've implemented an Apache Storm MQTT Spout. It works on a single server (Worker), but need to spread the load out across multiple servers, requiring multiple Storm Workers.

The only idea I've come up with is to have an intermediate MQTT Subscription service that handles load balancing and submits the data across the various spouts. Is there a better way to load balance MQTT data across subscribers?

Comment: were you able to figure this one out?

Comment: I never got any suggestions. I ended up significantly improving the Storm ingest bolt's performance and removed the need for load balancing for now. If I do get to that point I'm going to implement what I suggested above and create a storm bolt that gets the data and pushes it back out to a custom load balancing system, which would then get fed in to a scalable number of spouts.

Comment: well have a look at this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VoTclkxSago&feature=youtu.be&t=6m51s.

Comment: This guy uses mqtt -> kafka -> consumers, we can have storm spouts as consumers in this scenario. I haven't tried but this looks promising.